# How to create an Excel file with particular month date wise sheet in C# using Interop

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I want to create an Excel sheet where I want to create tabs with all dates of a particular month. For example tab names: 1 jan, 2jan, 3jan.....etc.

Also I have date-wise datatable like datatable1jan, datatble2jan, datatable3jan....etc. I want to create the Excel file with this datatable and tab name.

I know how to create an Excel file using interop like this:

```
Public static void CreateExcel_TabNameUnique( DataTable dt1,string ExcelFilePath, string Tab_Name1)
   {
       try
       {
           runDate = DateTime.Today;
           currMonth = DateTime.Today;
           object missing = Type.Missing;
           Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();
           oXL.Visible = false;
           Excel.Workbook oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(missing);
           Excel.Worksheet oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
           oSheet.Name = Tab_Name1;
           // column headings
           for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Columns.Count; i++)
           {
               oSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)] = dt1.Columns[i].ColumnName;
           }
           // rows
           for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
           {
               for (int j = 0; j < dt1.Columns.Count; j++)
               {
                   oSheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j + 1)] = dt1.Rows[i][j];
               }
           }
           if (ExcelFilePath != null && ExcelFilePath != "")
           {
               try
               {
                   oWB.SaveAs(ExcelFilePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook,
               missing, missing, missing, missing,
               Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
               missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
                   oWB.Close(missing, missing, missing);
                   oXL.UserControl = true;
                   oXL.Quit();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
       } 
   }
```

Comment: please can you provide some sample data that is in your datatable. The one you provided is not clear....  "datatable1jan,datatble2jan,datatable3jan"

Comment: its just table name tbl_1_jan1, tbl_2_jan....like. I want to include this datatable in excel sheet where sheet contain max 30 tabs which are dates of d particular month.

Comment: can anyone face this problem?